# End CSS Transition immediately during mouse-out

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I want to show a image preview of a link using CSS. The behavior is something like this, when an user hovers over the link, the image preview appears after 1sec, but on hovering out, the preview is removed immediately. Now to ensure the preview appears after 1sec, I have used the `transition` property as
`transition-property: visibility; transition-delay: 1s`. While this is ensuring the preview gets visible after 1sec, it's transition from visible to hidden is also delayed for 1sec for obvious reason. Can I make sure that only the transition from hidden to visible does take 1sec, and not the vice versa using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You sadly showed no code.

But I assume you had the `transition` property on a class or id... and the `:hover` just changing a property, which is good in order to apply the transition on mouse in and out.

Weird thing is you mention the `visibility` property, which cannot be transitionned because it is not a "number" property. Maybe you meant `opacity`...

If you have the `transition` property in the `:hover` rule... It apply on hover (read on mouse enter) but squarely do not apply no "not hover" (read mouse out).

```css
#target{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
}

#target:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: `visibilty` **can** be transitioned....sort of. You can delay it for instance. ☺